# Python - Instagram InstaPy for automated liking and following

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instapy

I wrote the following code that should like posts based on given tags and then follow the page. However, it seems the code runs, goes to those tags, but does not like or follow the page. My code is as follows:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="myusername",password="mypassword")
session.login()
session.like_by_tags(["dance", "mercedes"], amount=10, interact=True)
session.set_do_follow(enabled=True, percentage=100)
session.set_user_interact(amount=5, randomize=True, percentage=100)
session.end()
```

Output:
As I said above, the code runs fine, goes to the Instagram, logins, goes to those tags but doesn't like or follow any of them. I checked the output and it says the following (only giving some important summary below):

```
Unavailable Page: b'https://www.instagram.com/p/CZQuYMVKLwT/'
Image not liked: b'Unavailable Page'

|> LIKED 0 images  |  ALREADY LIKED: 0
        |> COMMENTED on 0 images
        |> FOLLOWED 0 users  |  ALREADY FOLLOWED: 0
        |> UNFOLLOWED 0 users
        |> LIKED 0 comments
        |> REPLIED to 0 comments
        |> INAPPROPRIATE images: 38
        |> NOT VALID users: 0
        |> WATCHED 0 story(ies)  |  WATCHED 0 reel(s)
```

Comment: Seems like there is an open//unresolved issue for this :
https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6421